# MySQL Workbench Rebuidling Database From Script File

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have a script file that has a bunch of create commands, and one that has a bunch of inserts. I would like to use these commands to rebuild my database on a different PC but I am struggling with how to accomplish this.

I just installed a fresh copy of MySQL Workbench and I created a new Model. Now what?!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the format of the script?  You should be able to just open the script file and then run the script as a query.

Comment: It is a .sql extension. So I should connect to the database and then in the query window I can copy/paste the code?

Comment: Yes, connect to the DB, load the file via either copy/paste or open it as a file, then run query.  I'll post an answer with screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to rebuild your tables from the script

First, connect to the database

[image: Connect to database]

Then, open your script file

[image: Open the script]

Run the query

[image: Run the query]

After that, you should have your tables restored.